# Not Getting the Command Line Parameter Output Properly

Tags: c#

I am trying to display the Number of Command Line Arguments entered as an input. Here is the block of my code.

```
//Argument: A, B, C, D

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ParamaterCount
{
    public class ParameterCount
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} command line arguments",args.Length);
            Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I am trying to run it. It gets out of the screen and I am getting nothing. I have also added the `Console.ReadLine()` statement but I am not able to enter inside the For Loop to count the iteration. Am I missing something ?
Thanks.

Output Should be like this.

```
Hello World,
You entered 4 Command Line Arguments
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: 1. have you stepped through your code to see what's going wrong? 2. What happened before you added the Readline()? 3. What exactly does "gets out of the screen" mean? I'm not clear on what's happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Actually*, you don't need to use [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because it reads input stream, not arguments that you provided.

That's the code you just need;

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} command line arguments", args.Length);
for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]);
}
```

Then follow these steps;

- Go `Run` and type `cmd.exe` which is shortcut for command line
- Go to your exe folder with `cd` (in my example `cd C:\Users\Soner\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProgramConsole\ProgramConsole\bin\Debug`)
- Run your exe with it's name and with `A B C D` (in my example `ProgramConsole.exe A B C D`)

Output will be;

```
Hello World
You have entered 4 command line arguments
A
B
C
D
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a console application arguments won't work like that. Your code is pretty OK, but note that you have to input the arguments at the run time, but since the first method which is called at the runtime is `Main()` so you haven't had the chance to provide the command line arguments. For achieving what you want, you have to run your compiled output application from command line, lets say your application name is `ConsoleApplication.exe`, so open the command line an then run `ConsoleApplication.exe` like this:

```
ConsoleApplication.exe A B C …
```

For further information see this: [Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx)

BTW: You can always run your console application using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead of <kbd>F5</kbd>, this will produce the same result as if you wrote a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `Console.ReadLine()` statement at the end of your `Main` method.
So your code should look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} command line arguments",args.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", args[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} command line arguments {1}",args.Length, string.Join(" ", args);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the console.readline() statement, instead Provide input while you are running your program from console. I have no idea about c# but in java you can achieve the above task as follow .

```
javac s.java
java s A B C D
```